# FT232H VCCIO pin voltage levels

Tags: ftdi

The datasheets for the FT232H chip are readily useful for interfacing a USB (5V) powered FT232 to any 3.3 volt RS232 (TTL-ish, at 3.3V) device, and for powering the FT232H with 3.3V. In both cases, one is instructed how to provide the VCCIO{1,2,3} pins with 3.3V. (Been there, done that!)

However, I can't make out from the datasheets if this allows me to interface the FT232H with a device operating at 1.8 volts by supplying 1.8V to the VCCIOn pins, or if I must power these pins with 3.3V and use a level converter.

Can I supply the VCCIO pins with the 1.8V of some target device and aassume that the FT232H chip applies an 1.8V logic?

Comment: Page 40 shows that VCCIO should be in the 2.97 to 3.3V, so yes, you need a level converter or maybe find out if the device connected to the FTDI is 3v3 tolerant despite being 1v8 normally.

Comment: @Big6 Thanks, and that's what I expect. Have you happened to try otherwise?

Comment: I have not tried that with any of the boards (3 or 4) I've designed in the past,  can't tell what it would do.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question in the last few days?  *Someone* definitely did.

Comment: Does it need to be a FT232H? Because maybe FT232R or FT231X might be a better match for your application.

Comment: @ChrisStratton No, I di not ask that question a few days ago. And yes, I searched for answers before I asked. Why do are ask?